# Error in Jenkins Job Sloccount: command not found

Tags: jenkins

One of the steps in my Jenkins job is to run the "sloccount command".

I get an error "sloccount: command not found" but when I tried to run it form the command line it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **sloccount** isn't installed on the machine where the job is executed.

If you have master/slave constellation **sloccount** has to be installed on the slave.